# naked expression at top level Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell

Tags: haskell

With the following program:

```
pair :: Int -> Bool
pair x ((x `mod` 2) == 0 )
```

I get the error:

```
pair.hs:2:1: error:
  Parse error: naked expression at top level 
  Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot the `=` between `x` and `(`.

Comment: Haskell however has already an `even` function: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:even This is likely implemented with bit operations (checking the last bit), so likely it is faster than using modulo.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes this what I forget thank you , yes I just used the code to test because I had an error in another code , and I see that I don't make = ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to `` pair x = ((x `mod` 2) == 0 ) ``.